# Get built in method signature - Python

Tags: python, function, arguments

How do I get the signature of built in methods?
Example: dict().get(k)

```
>> a = dict().get
>> a
<built-in method get of dict object at 0x1003aafd0>
>> a.__doc__
'D.get(k[,d]) -> D[k] if k in D, else d.  d defaults to None.'
>> import inspect
>> inspect.getargspec(a)
TypeError: <built-in method get of dict object at 0x100377250> is not a Python function
```

I would like to see the result like this

```
>> a.some_function()
('key', 'default'=None)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get arguments list of a built-in Python class constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628081/how-to-get-arguments-list-of-a-built-in-python-class-constructor)

Comment: Related: http://bugs.python.org/issue1748064 Short summary: you can't (in CPython) at the moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think this is possible for the built-in functions in python that are implemented in C. See [this](http://bugs.python.org/issue1748064) bug discussion for further details.